# Cypress: Finding elements with text inside a list of elements

Tags: list, cypress

For a Java/kotlin geek, I'm finding Cypress a bit hard to work with, since I'm used to the way Java/Kotlin and Selenium works.

In this example, I'm having some trouble getting a table with several rows of data, and creating an elegant method of getting a specific td in a specific row.

Consider this simplified markup:

```html
<table>
 <tr data-e2e-selector="case-row">
  <td data-e2e-selector="date">3. sep</td>
  <td data-e2e-selecto=""name">Frank</td>
 </tr>
 <tr data-e2e-selector="case-row">
  <td data-e2e-selector="date">12. sep</td>
  <td data-e2e-selecto=""name">Ola</td>
 ....
 ....
 <tr data-e2e-selector="case-row">
  <td data-e2e-selector="date">23. sep</td>
  <td data-e2e-selecto=""name">Morgan</td>
</table>
```

I can get the whole set of rows like this:

```js
cy.get('[data-e2e-selector="case-row]')
```

That gives me a list/array of the correct number of rows.

However, if I want to get for instance the `data-e2e-selector="date"` field from the first, last or other specific row, I'm running into problems.

I would think that this line would verify the "date" field of the FIRST row:

```js
cy.get('[data-e2e-selector=case-row]').first().get('[data-e2e-selector=innsendtDato]').should('contain.text', "3. sep")
```

But it doesn't, apparently. Because if the cypress runner reports this ("successful") check:

> -assert- expected '[ <td#sakInnsendtDato_0.ng-star-inserted>, 20 more... ]' to contain text '23. sep'

which seems to indicate that it's been looking through all 21 rows to find a  with the expected value. Whereas I want to know if it's in the FIRST.

To verify this, if I change "first()" to "last()", it will also verify successfully.

So, how does this work?

I've also tried using index to indicate the first row, instead of first() or last(), but that gives a compile error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Cypress command you want to use is `cy.find()`.](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/find) This will search a descendant DOM element, where `cy.get()` starts from the top of the DOM for searching. [From the `cy.get()` documentation:](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/get#Get-vs-Find)

> The `cy.get` command always starts its search from the cy.root element. In most cases, it is the document element, unless used inside the .within() command. The .find command starts its search from the current subject.

```js
cy.get('[data-e2e-selector=case-row]')
  .first()
  .find('[data-e2e-selector=innsendtDato]')
  .should('contain.text', "3. sep");
```

Alternatively, you could use `.within()` to yield the first element and then use `cy.get()` within that callback.

```js
cy.get('[data-e2e-selector=case-row]')
  .first()
  .within(($el) => {
    cy.get('[data-e2e-selector=innsendtDato]')
      .should('contain.text', "3. sep");
  });
```

When chaining a `cy.get()` off of the your `.first()` command, you're not actually using the yield of the `.first()` command to perform your search. The test is marked as passed because the result of the second `cy.get()` (innsendtDato) yields 21 elements (all elements found by `cy.get('[data-e2e-selector=innsendtDato]')`) and at least one of those elements does contain the text `3. sep`.

Comment: This worked exactly how I wanted. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 5):

The message `expected '[ <td#sakInnsendtDato_0.ng-star-inserted>, 20 more... ]' to contain text...` is saying

> Hey I found 21 elements from your query and ***at least one of them*** has the text you want.

Another way to narrow down the selection is to use `contains(/^3. sep$/)` - that command only ever returns one element.

**NOTE** I'm using regex to find the string, since one date can be part of another date e.g `3. sep` and `23. sep`.

```js
cy.get('table#my-table [data-e2e-selector=innsendtDato]')    // 21 elements
  .contains(/^3. sep$/)                       // filter based on the text
  .should('have.length', 1)                   // only one matches

cy.contains('table#my-table [data-e2e-selector=innsendtDato]', /^3. sep$/)  
  .should('have.length', 1)                   // only one matches
```

If you want to work with the `case-row`, you can specify that element instead of the date element.

The children will also be checked, but the element returned is the one specified by the selector.

```js
cy.contains('table#my-table [data-e2e-selector="case-row"]', /^3. sep$/)  
  .should('have.length', 1)
```

---

#### Verifying the text is on the nth row

There is an `index()` method that will tell you which row has the text searched for.

For example, the first and second rows:

```js
cy.get('table#my-table [data-e2e-selector=date]')
  .contains(/^3. sep$/)
  .parent()           // to parent row 
  .invoke('index')
  .should('eq', 0)    // "3 Sep" is on the first parent
```

```js
cy.get('table#my-table [data-e2e-selector=date]')
  .contains(/^12. sep$/)
  .parent()           // to parent row  
  .invoke('index')
  .should('eq', 1)    // "12 Sep" is on the second parent
```

or

```js
cy.contains('table#my-table [data-e2e-selector="case-row"]', /^3. sep$/)  
  .invoke('index')
  .should('eq', 0)    // "3 Sep" is on the first parent
```

```js
cy.contains('table#my-table [data-e2e-selector="case-row"]', /^3. sep$/)  
  .invoke('index')
  .should('eq', 1)    // "12 Sep" is on the second parent
```

Comment: These all gives this error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [data-e2e-selector="case-row]:cy-contains('23. sep'), [data-e2e-selector="case-row][type='submit'][value~='23. sep']. In any case, there's no submit in the table.

Comment: Is there also a simple way to verify that an element containing a string comes BEFORE another element containing another string, in the same sort of list?

Comment: Yes, `.contains()` is problematic for a calendar table where one date can be part of another date - "3. sep" also matches with "23. sep". You would need regex instead of string. I'll show how that looks.

Answer (score 3):

In this case you don't really need the `case-row` selector in the chain, you can just apply `.first()` to `innsendtDato`.

```js
cy.get('[data-e2e-selector=innsendtDato]').first().should('contain.text', "3. sep")
```

---

The key thing you missed in your test is the concept of parent and child commands.

See [Parent Commands](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands#Parent-Commands)

> Parent commands always begin a new chain of commands.
>
> Even if you've chained it off of a previous command, parent commands will always start a new chain, and ***ignore previously yielded subjects***.

`.get('[data-e2e-selector=innsendtDato]')` is a **Parent** command, so it ignores the `.first()` that comes before it.

Comment: But if I don't use the case-row selector, if there was another element called "innsendtDato" on the page, that would be wrongly selected. I Selenium I would create a class of the whole table, then classes of each row, and use methods to get the values.

Comment: If you have other instances of `innsendtDato` in the page you want to ignore, just add additional specifier to the selector such as `table#my-table` - see my answer, I added that to illustrate.

Comment: But obviously that's a different issue to the one in your question - the improper chaining of `.get()`.